# arduino ide empty project does not compile

Tags: arduino, telegram, esp32

I am facing a issue trying to compile a empty project, with just libraries imported. Somehow the asynctelegram2 library is causing it to fail. removing that library makes it work again. i am not able to figure out what the problem is.. any help is greatly appreciated.. the board is a Lolin TTGO esp32 based board.

.ino file:

```
#include <TFT_eSPI.h> // Graphics and font library
#include <SPI.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <Timezone.h>    // https://github.com/JChristensen/Timezone
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <AsyncTelegram2.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include "FS.h"
#include "SD.h"

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Error output:

```
WARNING: library Timezone claims to run on avr architecture(s) and may be incompatible with your current board which runs on esp32 architecture(s).
In file included from C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\test_compile\test_compile.ino:9:0:
C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AsyncTelegram2\src/AsyncTelegram2.h: In member function 'bool AsyncTelegram2::sendPhoto(int64_t, const char*, fs::FS&, const char*)':
C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AsyncTelegram2\src/AsyncTelegram2.h:249:9: error: 'File' was not declared in this scope
         File file = fs.open(filename, "r");
         ^
C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AsyncTelegram2\src/AsyncTelegram2.h:249:9: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\TFT_eSPI/Processors/TFT_eSPI_ESP32.h:137:0,
                 from C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\TFT_eSPI/TFT_eSPI.h:72,
                 from C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\test_compile\test_compile.ino:1:
C:\Users\shark\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\libraries\FS\src/FS.h:47:7: note:   'fs::File'
 class File : public Stream
       ^
In file included from C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\test_compile\test_compile.ino:9:0:
C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AsyncTelegram2\src/AsyncTelegram2.h:250:76: error: 'file' was not declared in this scope
         bool res = sendStream(chat_id, "sendPhoto", "image/jpeg", "photo", file, file.size(), caption);
                                                                            ^
C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AsyncTelegram2\src/AsyncTelegram2.h: In member function 'bool AsyncTelegram2::sendPhoto(const TBMessage&, const char*, fs::FS&, const char*)':
C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AsyncTelegram2\src/AsyncTelegram2.h:256:9: error: 'File' was not declared in this scope
         File file = fs.open(filename, "r");
         ^
C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AsyncTelegram2\src/AsyncTelegram2.h:256:9: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\TFT_eSPI/Processors/TFT_eSPI_ESP32.h:137:0,
                 from C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\TFT_eSPI/TFT_eSPI.h:72,
                 from C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\test_compile\test_compile.ino:1:
C:\Users\shark\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\libraries\FS\src/FS.h:47:7: note:   'fs::File'
 class File : public Stream
       ^
In file included from C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\test_compile\test_compile.ino:9:0:
C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AsyncTelegram2\src/AsyncTelegram2.h:257:79: error: 'file' was not declared in this scope
         bool res = sendStream(msg.chatId, "sendPhoto", "image/jpeg", "photo", file, file.size(), caption);
                                                                               ^
C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AsyncTelegram2\src/AsyncTelegram2.h: In member function 'bool AsyncTelegram2::sendPhotoByFile(int64_t, const char*, fs::FS&)':
C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AsyncTelegram2\src/AsyncTelegram2.h:294:9: error: 'File' was not declared in this scope
         File file = fs.open(filename, "r");
         ^
C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AsyncTelegram2\src/AsyncTelegram2.h:294:9: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\TFT_eSPI/Processors/TFT_eSPI_ESP32.h:137:0,
                 from C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\TFT_eSPI/TFT_eSPI.h:72,
                 from C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\test_compile\test_compile.ino:1:
C:\Users\shark\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\libraries\FS\src/FS.h:47:7: note:   'fs::File'
 class File : public Stream
       ^
In file included from C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\test_compile\test_compile.ino:9:0:
C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AsyncTelegram2\src/AsyncTelegram2.h:295:24: error: 'file' was not declared in this scope
         Serial.println(file.size());
                        ^
Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"
 Used: C:\Users\shark\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\libraries\WiFi
 Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\WiFi
Multiple libraries were found for "NTPClient.h"
 Used: C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\NTPClient
 Not used: C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\NTPClient-master
Multiple libraries were found for "SD.h"
 Used: C:\Users\shark\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\libraries\SD
 Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SD
 Not used: C:\Users\shark\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SD
exit status 1
Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module.
```

Answer (score 0):

From AsyncTelegram2 [documentation](https://github.com/cotestatnt/AsyncTelegram2):

It relies on ArduinoJson v6 library so, in order to use a AsyncTelegram2 object, you need to install the ArduinoJson library first.

Comment: Oddly, if you put the telegram library on top of the list as first, it compiles without problems..